# How to Trigger setInterval() by checking and clearInterval() on unchecking a Checkbox, using Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to initiate a setInterval(), when the checkbox is checked and on unchecking the checkbox, I want to clear the interval using clearInterval().

But, something is going wrong, and the clearInterval() is not working. I will be glad if anyone can help me out here.

```js
document.getElementById('slide').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        var auto= setInterval(function () {
            console.log('hello');
        },1000);
        
    }
    else{
        console.log("setInterval Cleared");
        var auto=clearInterval(auto);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="slide-input">
  <input type="checkbox" id="slide"> Slide
</div>
```

Comment: define the `var auto` outside of the change function scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you do the `clearInterval` you don't have the id of the interval saved because the variable is created in the function scope. You should declare it one level top:

```
var auto;
document.getElementById('slide').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        auto = setInterval(function () {
            console.log('hello');
        },1000);

    }
    else{
        console.log("setInterval Cleared");
        auto = clearInterval(auto);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to go:

```js
var auto = null;
document.getElementById('slide').addEventListener('change', function() {
    
    if(this.checked) {
        auto=setInterval(function () {
            console.log('hello');
        },1000);
    }
    else{
        console.log("setInterval Cleared");
        clearInterval(auto);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="slide-input">
  <input type="checkbox" id="slide"> Slide
</div>
```

You must declare the `var auto` out of the scope of the event listener so the clearInterval function knows which interval needs to be cleared